# Has Jim Jordan said what he intends to do to pass the Republican objectives into law?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, republican-party

Jim Jordan, one of the founders of the Freedom Caucus, often described as the "hard right" in some of the press, is the Republican speaker-nominee ([was](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/14/politics/jim-jordan-house-speaker-race/index.html) thus elected by secret ballot of the Republican caucus 155 to 55) although he still needs a majority on floor to take the gavel, and only 5 Republican votes in the open against him would sink that.

One of the main complaints against the former speaker McCarthy was that he failed to outline a strategy of how he intended to pass the Republican objectives past the [narrow] Democratic majority in the Senate, or past the presidential veto. (And related to that complaint was that instead McCarthy made ad hoc compromises.) Has Jim Jordan said anything in that regard, i.e. laid out a strategy for overcoming Democratic votes/vetoes?

Comment: Is this a serious question? To my knowledge, Jordan has never expressed anything resembling a policy objective; he's mainly concerned himself with an agenda of attacks on and retributions against people he views as anti-Trump. He's running for speaker on a bully pulpit, not out of any concern for GOP priorities.

Comment: I wonder whether they formally declared their strategy of 'no compromise' somewhere. Use all legal means to block any policy that does not match their positions to 100% and expect everyone else to cave in to their positions or accept complete break down of any political process.

Comment: @quarague: yeah, something like that. "[Belgium](https://caw.ceu.edu/other-activities/academic-blog/politics/how-did-belgium-manage-to-survive-without-having-agovernment)+ strategy", if I am to coin a term.

Comment: @Fizz I don't think this could work anywhere near as well in the US as it did in Belgium. As I understand it the US would run into a permanent government shutdown after a few months at best because of the debt ceiling and no possibility of increasing it without a government.

Answer (score 4):

> **Question:**
>
> Has Jim Jordan said what he intends to do to pass the Republican objectives into law?

**Short Answer:**

The three ways to get anything done in Congress with such a tight majority are:

- compromise
- consensus building.
- persuasive arguments (intelligence)

Jim Jordan is singularly unsuited to perform any of these actions.
So no, he has no plan, no objective, and no possibility to be successful as speaker.  This inability to compromise even with his own party, is on full display with the rudderless House of Representatives.  Jim Jordan's "freedom caucus" has been the bane of existence for the last 3 Republican speakers.

**Answer:**

No Jim Jordan,  long one of the ***[the most despised men in Congress](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/07/27/jordan-meadows-trump-allies-congress-745121)***  has no way to advance Republican issues, because.

1. He has built his career on his in ability to compromise.

> **[I worked for two former (Republican) speakers. It’s surreal that Jim Jordan could be next.](https://www.msnbc.com/opinion/msnbc-opinion/jim-jordan-house-speaker-maga-hardliner-republican-rcna119252)**
>
> The job of speaker requires difficult decisions, policymaking nuance and compromise. Jordan has rejected these through his career, instead preaching rigidity, purity and the fanciful notion that any conservative outcome can be had simply by fighting harder.

2. He is universally condemned among Democrats.

**[CNN’s Tapper to Nancy Mace: ‘Name one Democrat who trusts Jim Jordan’](https://www.msnbc.com/opinion/msnbc-opinion/jim-jordan-house-speaker-maga-hardliner-republican-rcna119252)**

3. He is generally condemned among Republicans.

**['Same stupid clown car with a different driver': Hear GOP lawmaker's warning to party](https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2023/10/05/house-speaker-gaetz-jordan-scalise-clown-car-dusty-johnson-cnc-vpx-sot.cnn)**

4. He is dumber than a sack of rocks.

- **[Jim Jordan’s utter stupidity is on full display right now on Twitter](https://www.queerty.com/jim-jordans-utter-stupidity-full-display-right-now-twitter-20211223)**
- **[Jim Jordan mocked for "monumentally dumb" attempt to defend Trump](https://www.salon.com/2021/02/16/jim-jordan-mocked-for-monumentally-dumb-attempt-to-defend-trump_partner/)**
- **[James Carville Wants ‘Borderline Stupid’ Comer and Jordan To Lead Biden Impeachment Push: ‘I So Want Them To Do This’](https://www.mediaite.com/politics/james-carville-wants-borderline-stupid-comer-and-jordan-to-lead-biden-impeachment-push-i-so-want-them-to-do-this/)**
- **[What’s Next for the House? Nobody Knows… but It Will Be Dumb](https://www.queerty.com/jim-jordans-utter-stupidity-full-display-right-now-twitter-20211223)**
- **[Jim Jordan’s New Committee Is an Absurd Waste of Time, Even for Him](https://www.themarysue.com/jim-jordan-republicans-absurd-new-committee/)**

> **Ken Olin on X**
>
> "Jim Jordan is an idiot. I'm serious. He's not an intelligent human being. He's loud, he's aggressive, he's obnoxious, and he's stupid."

His highest non government job was as an assistant wrestling coach at Ohio State, where the captain of the wrestling team accused him of covering up a sexual abuse scandal.

**[Ex-Ohio State Wrestler Says Rep. Jim Jordan Involved in Sexual Abuse Cover-Up](https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2876074-ex-ohio-state-wrestler-says-rep-jim-jordan-involved-in-sexual-abuse-cover-up)**

He has a law degree, but never passed the bar exam so he's not a lawyer; but he is chairman of the Judiciary committee.  The Judiciary committee where he has been mocked by several local prosecutors for not understanding the law.

- **[‘The Single Most Humiliating Letter Ever Received’: Lawrence O’Donnell Brutally Mocks Jim Jordan’s Attempt to Get Alvin Bragg to Testify](https://www.mediaite.com/politics/the-single-most-humiliating-letter-ever-received-lawrence-odonnell-brutally-mocks-jim-jordans-attempt-to-get-alvin-bragg-to-testify/)**
- **[Fani Willis mocks Rep. Jim Jordan's effort to meddle in Trump's Georgia election conspiracy case](https://www.nydailynews.com/2023/09/07/fani-willis-mocks-rep-jim-jordans-effort-to-meddle-in-trumps-georgia-election-conspiracy-case/)**

On a happy note,  Jim Jordan chance of becoming speaker are exceedingly slim due to all of the above.

**Addendum:**

Kevin McCarthy was vacated from the speakership for 2 reasons.

1. He relied on Democrat votes to avert a government shutdown.

> **[Rep. Matt Gaetz moves to oust Kevin McCarthy as House speaker](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/matt-gaetz-kevin-mccarthy-speaker-fight/)**
>
> Hard-right Republicans are making good on a threat to remove House Speaker Kevin McCarthy as Rep. Matt Gaetz moved to oust him on Monday.
> The motion came two days after McCarthy relied heavily on the votes of House Democrats on Saturday to pass a bill to extend government funding for 45 days to avert a shutdown.

2. He refused to block Rep. Matt Gatz ethics investigation for statutory Rape.

> **[House Speaker McCarthy defends leadership, says Gaetz has ‘personal’ issues](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/10/03/house-speaker-mccarthy-defends-leadership-says-gaetz-has-personal-issues.html)**
>
> McCarthy accused Gaetz of harboring a grudge over the speaker’s refusal to quash a congressional ethics complaint against him that is related to allegations of sexual misconduct.

Comment: Your point 1. nicely addresses OPs question, point 2 and 3 can also be seen as supporting the argument. But while I agree that point 4 is correct I don't see what it has to do with the question asked.

Comment: @quarague,   Intelligence would be a quality which might overcome the other 3 deficiencies and lead to getting something done.   The premise is with a dearth of all 4 necessary qualities to succeed, he lacks the ability to accomplish anything, except blocking that which would be his responsibility to achieve.  Which I guess he will try to sell as an accomplishment.